# How to write a CMAKE file which successfully links gstreamer basic tutorial 5

Tags: cmake, gstreamer

I'm trying to write a CMAKE file which will compile the code found [here](https://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/documentation/tutorials/basic/toolkit-integration.html?gi-language=c).

My current CMAKE file looks like this and has successfully compiled and linked the previous tutorials. It also compiles this one but when linking I get the following error:

```
undefined reference to `gst_video_overlay_get_type'
undefined reference to `gst_video_overlay_set_window_handle'
```

The CMAKE file looks like so:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.18)
project(gstreamer)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 20)

find_package(PkgConfig REQUIRED)
pkg_check_modules(GTK3 REQUIRED gtk+-3.0)

pkg_search_module(GST REQUIRED gstreamer-1.0>=1.4
        gstreamer-sdp-1.0>=1.4
        gstreamer-app-1.0>=1.4
        gstreamer-video-1.0>=1.4
        )


add_executable(gstreamer main.cpp)

target_include_directories(gstreamer PRIVATE ${GTK3_INCLUDE_DIRS} ${GST_INCLUDE_DIRS})
target_link_libraries(gstreamer ${GTK3_LIBRARIES} ${GST_LIBRARIES})
```

Other SO posts have suggested linking `gstreamer-video-1.0` which I believe I am in:

```
target_link_libraries(gstreamer ${GST_LIBRARIES})
```

If I've misunderstood how PkgConfig works I'd much appreciate an explanation.

Thanks

Comment: As you can deduce from function's naming (and find confirmation in the [documentation](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/module/FindPkgConfig.html), `pkg_check_modules` searches **multiple modules** but `pkg_search_module` searches only a **single module**. But you use `pkg_search_module` for a list of modules.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is how it works with modern target-based CMake:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.15.3)
project(gstreamer)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 20)

find_package(PkgConfig REQUIRED)
pkg_check_modules(gtk3 REQUIRED IMPORTED_TARGET gtk+-3.0)
pkg_search_module(gstreamer REQUIRED IMPORTED_TARGET gstreamer-1.0>=1.4)
pkg_search_module(gstreamer-sdp REQUIRED IMPORTED_TARGET gstreamer-sdp-1.0>=1.4)
pkg_search_module(gstreamer-app REQUIRED IMPORTED_TARGET gstreamer-app-1.0>=1.4)
pkg_search_module(gstreamer-video REQUIRED IMPORTED_TARGET gstreamer-video-1.0>=1.4)

add_executable(my-gstreamer-app main.cpp)

target_link_libraries(my-gstreamer-app
    PkgConfig::gtk3
    PkgConfig::gstreamer
    PkgConfig::gstreamer-sdp
    PkgConfig::gstreamer-app
    PkgConfig::gstreamer-video
)
```

Note the absence of `target_include_directories`. The imported targets contain all of this information, including linker flags, compiler flags, library paths, include paths, etc. Linking to the imported targets via `target_link_libraries` will pull all `PUBLIC` and `INTERFACE` properties from them into the `my-gstreamer-app` target.

Answer (score 5):

you can try:

```
find_package(PkgConfig) 
pkg_search_module(GLIB REQUIRED glib-2.0) 
pkg_check_modules(GSTREAMER REQUIRED gstreamer-1.0)
pkg_check_modules(GST_APP REQUIRED gstreamer-app-1.0)
pkg_check_modules(GST_VIDEO REQUIRED gstreamer-video-1.0)
```

and

`target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} ${GST_APP_LIBRARIES} ${GST_VIDEO_LIBRARIES})`

Comment: With modern cmake: `target_link_libraries(gstreamer PkgConfig::GLIB PkgConfig::GSTREAMER PkgConfig::GST_APP PkgConfig::GST_VIDEO)`. This will not only link the libraries but also add its header include paths, so you can leave out the `target_include_directories` call.